# Having for loop output sets of numbers?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have the following code

```
    for (int k=0; k<maxThreads; k++) {
        int firstpart = k * tasksPerThread;
        int secondpart = ((k+1) * tasksPerThread) - 1;
        System.out.println(firstpart + "," + secondpart);
    }
```

Where maxThreads is inputted by the user and tasksPerThread is 10/maxThreads. MaxThreads is never less than 1. This outputs pairs of numbers. For example, if maxThreads = 2 (making tasksPerThread = 5) then it outputs

```
0,4
5,9
```

Covering all ten values 0-9

I want all ten values to be covered if maxThreads = 4. Right now the code outputs this

```
0,1
2,3
4,5
6,7
```

But I would like it to cover 0-9. So ideally it would output

```
0-2
3-5
6-7
8-9
```

Or really any combination that has maxThreads number of sets of numbers and covers 0-9. How can I adjust the for loop to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I edited the question so that 5 was not written twice.

Answer (score 1):

it is being rounded down I think, try using ceiling.

Comment: well I only want it to output four (or whatever number maxthreads is) sets of numbers. However the four sets must cover 0-9

Comment: yeah i realized that, changed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take one thread more in the `tasksPerThread` variable in this case. You're calculating it as `10/maxThreads` but you need to apply **ceiling** to it.

```
int tasksPerThread = Math.ceil(10/(double) maxThreads);
```

Note that you have to get `maxThreads` as a double, because if you take it as an `int`, the div result will always be an `int`.

This should do it:

```
 int tasksPerThread = Math.ceil(10/(double) maxThreads);
 for (int k=0; k<maxThreads; k++) {
    int firstpart = k * tasksPerThread;
    int secondpart = ((k+1) * tasksPerThread) - 1;
    System.out.println(firstpart + "," + secondpart);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by ceiling?

Comment: It means to be rounded up if the value is not exactly an integer value. For example if the div result is 2.1 it will go to 3 tasks per thread, which is what you need. For the last thread just include the tasks you have in surplus.

Comment: Thank you. It now displays 0,2
3,5
6,8
9,11 however i would like it to stop at 9 if possible. How would I do this?

Comment: Unfortunately the program may only have 10 tasks and it outputs an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: As it is, you're going above 10. Just control second part doesn't take a value above that and if it takes it, set it to the limit. Did you change your code? As far as I know, `IndexOutOfBoundsException` can only be thrown when you've arrays or lists (not in this case).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like :

```
for (int k = 0; k < maxThreads; k++) {
  int firstpart = (int) (k * tasksPerThread);
  int secondpart = (int) (((k + 1) * tasksPerThread) - 1);
  System.out.println(firstpart + "," + secondpart);
}
```

where `tasksPerThread` is computed as :

```
double tasksPerThread = 10.0 / maxThreads;
```

or equivalently

```
double tasksPerThread = 10 / (double) maxThreads;
```

Comment: `tasksPerThread` cannot aquire `double` ranged values, otherwise the results could get decimals. You can't have half of a task in a thread, no?

Comment: We're casting all final results to `int` so there will not be any decimals.

Answer (score 1):

This code will divide up n tasks among `maxThreads` threads:

```
public static void schedule(int n, int maxThreads) {
    int tasksPerThread = (n + maxThreads - 1) / maxThreads;
    int nExtra = tasksPerThread * maxThreads - n;
    int nFull = tasksPerThread * (maxThreads - nExtra);
    int start = 0;
    while (start < nFull) {
        int end = start + tasksPerThread - 1;
        System.out.printf("%1$d,%2$d%n", start, end);
        start = end + 1;
    }
    while (start < n) {
        int end = start + tasksPerThread - 2;
        System.out.printf("%1$d,%2$d%n", start, end);
        start = end + 1;
    }
}
```